# Schedule a draft to auto publish?

Tags: entry, draft

Is there a way to schedule a **draft** of a entry to go live?

Answer (score 9):

If the entry is not already published, just set the `Post Date` to a date in the future.

[image: Future Post]

That will set the entry to what Craft calls `Pending`. On the entry's index, the status indicator will be orange (instead of green).

[image: Future Entry]

If the entry is already currently published, no. That'd be a [feature request](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/864). I agree, it would be great to be able to "publish over" the current edition (say for a contest or what not). If you set a draft's entry to a future date, Craft will un-publish the entry and set the status to pending.

You could work around this in Twig though. Say you want to have the entry change on 11/10. Set up a new Draft, name it `Will Go Live on 11/10` (or whatever). Then in your template:

```
{% if now|date('U') > "2015-11-10"|date('U') %}

{% set theDrafts = craft.entryRevisions.getDraftsByEntryId(entry.id) %}

{# keep the "old" entry around just in case #}
{% set oldEntry = entry %}

        {%for i in theDrafts %}

            {# look for the specific draft and set if it exists #}

            {% if i.name == "Will Go Live on 11/10" %}
                {% set entry = i %}
            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}

{% endif %}

{# template as normal #}
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The latter is the use case I am looking for... especially for single entries.